# div width problem...problem is cross browser

Tags: browser, cross-browser, width, css

I have a div having two buttons inside it as |Add| and |Cancel|. I didnt set any width to that div intially and as a result they were displayed vertically not in horizontal.then i add width in % to 11.5%.now the display is ok in moz but not in chrome and ie.i cant use pixels neither in height nor width.problem explanied by example

---

|***_*__*_*__*_***|    // a textbox

|Add|                  //initially with no width
|Cancel|

//after width to 11.5% in moz

---

|***_*__*_*__*_***|

```
 |Add| |Cancel|
```

//after width to 11.5% in chrome and ie

---

|***_*__*_*__*_***|

|Add| |Cancel|

so u can see that in moz it is aligned to the above textbox but not in ie and chrome.hope sum ie hack or chrome hack may lead to correct result..or ONLY a MOZ hack..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably because by default, if left to their own will, different browsers render things differently.

You should use CSS resets so the default behavior of most browsers will be the same.

[Have a look here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/)

Comment: i m using reset css..but how can i align them in different browsers??min-width gets over ride as i have to use 'height' for ie and its causing all trouble

Comment: ok input by default is a block element that is why they are displayed vertically. if you want them to display horizontally juse make them both style='float:left;' and give the right hand one a margin-left so it will not be right against the other one.

Comment: hey i got da solution...i float that container div to right..but i had to explicitly float buttons too to  float right..and that worked...thanks for your precious tym.

Answer (score 0):

You can give `display:inline;`to the div that you added buttons and giv width to `width:auto;`.If you specify the width for Div, it'll not display in chrome.Use space between px like  `margin-left:10 px`.You can validate your errors using validation toolbar.It will be very useful to specify the mistakes in CSS.